# Can't run program because of JDK/JRE Error

Tags: java

Whenever I try to run a program that uses JDK (I have JDK-13.0.1) it sends me the following message via Windows 10 console:

> Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
> Press any key to continue . . .

I had JRE installed but the program still ended up in Error, when I read the program's Error Log it said:

> "Remember to NOT use JRE, it is NOT compatible, you must use JDK"

So I uninstalled JRE, installed JDK and tried to run it, when I ran the Program install Build, it worked just fine (Which was the one that originally told me to NOT use JRE), but when I ran the build for the program itself, It gave me that message, I have deleted all JRE/JDK related files, delete all of the program related files, reinstalled both the program and the JDK and it still happens...
I am clueless in what to do, please help.

JAVA_HOME Variable:
[image: JAVA_HOME Variable]

[Update]
I have tried a mixture of personal knowledge, suggestions given here, articles read and intuition.
This resulted in me discovering what was wrong.
My Java version is set to a non-existing file on the computer (The JRE)

How do I change the Java version to the JDK?

Comment: try to print your JAVA_HOME environment variable. What does it show? I suspect that it is still pointing to the old installation. You need then to modify it

Comment: What does java -version output in the command line? Should give a proper version.

Comment: Open a command prompt and enter the command: `where java`. What output do you get?

Comment: Abra, when I run where java the following message apears:                            C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

Comment: alainlompo, I have edited the original question body with an image of my JAVA_HOME variable

Comment: Steven De Groote, whenever I ran that command on the console I received the following message: Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'

Comment: Hello everyone, I have updated the current problem with a more specific one, thru all the help that was given to me here and some trial and error, I would very much appreciate if you could give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 problems:

1. You are using an Editor / IDE that has standalone settings for JDK/JRE path
2. Your build system has was set to use a specific JDK

In which Editor / IDE you use to run your java code?

Comment: Tuan Tran, I am still kind of new to the world of programming and honestly kind of young as well, do to that, I am not sure about any of that info... Tho I am using 2 things: Gradle and CompileKotlin, I am still unsure what they are but they came attached to the program files. I think the Program was originally  made in JDK 8 but I am not sure what version of JDK 8, Hope this is helpful in any way.